# Regex and Excel Cells

Tags: c#, .net, regex

There is a .NET opensource library called NPOI that allows you to manipulate Excel files.  Unfortunately, their ShiftRows function does not adjust any cell references in formulas.

Therefore, I need to create a regex pattern to update them. Take for example a cell containing the following formula:

=(B7/C9) * (A10-B4)

I would like to bump any row references by 1 thus becoming

=(B8/C10) * (A11-B5)

Basically, I just need a pattern that will extract the numbers out into a "MatchCollection". I can do the rest.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my answer to another question: [Which regular expression is able to select excel column names in a formula in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854827/which-regular-expression-is-able-to-select-excel-column-names-in-a-formula-in-c/859995#859995)

In that answer I match formulas and include code to increment the cell number (and column naming). Also, do a search on Excel column naming here and you'll find other ways to get the names generated or incremented. I probably could shorten the IncrementColumn MatchEvaluator's code using one of those methods but that's what I came up with at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be very careful using regular expressions for this purpose.
Excel formulas can become very complex, especially with user-defined functions or when  functions apply to ranges.
NPOI contains a Formula evaluation library and I think you should have a look at this as well - especially if the spreadsheets are out of your control.

Comment: Actually, I will have control of the spreadsheet. I will be exporting some data into a "template.xls" so there will be no surprises. Thanks for your reply.